# Breaking out of an for statement in Java

Tags: java

If i do something like this

```
boolean ret;
for(int i = 2;i<30;i++) {
  if ( 30%i == 0){
    ret = true;
  } else {
    ret = false;
  }
}
```

ret becomes true allready at 2, but also at 5,10 15, is there anyway to break out of the for statement as soon as ret becomes true?

Comment: Surely you mean "break out of the for statement"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the `break` command

```
boolean ret = false;
for(int i = 2; i < 30; i++){
    if(30%i == 0){
       ret = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, will give you credit as soon as i can :-)

Comment: Note that if you're inside a function and willing to return something if some condition is met, you can use `return x;` and it will act as a break, too.

Comment: @SteffenHvid Ensure that you know how this code works.  You're not breaking the "if".  You're breaking out of the loop.

Comment: If you are working with that easy for loops, this would be a good way to go, but i wouldn´t recomment them for more complex loops, espacially with nested loops, since it hinders the readability

Answer (score 3):

Without using a structure breaking instruction, you can simply perform a check in the for condition.

```
boolean ret = false;
for(int i = 2;i<30 && !ret;i++) {
    if ( 30%i == 0){
        ret = true;
    } else {
        ret = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't break out of an `if`. By the time it has decided which way the condition goes, it's already over and there's nothing left to skip. You only can break out of a loop, like the `for`.

But the incomparably better way of exiting early is to put your sample code into a method and use `return`. More readable, and with a good method name the purpose of the entire code (and the `return`) is immediately clear.